# A difficult question on representing a square by a sum of 4 (or 5 ) squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

The question above is not about the decomposition of a square $$m^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 $$ as a sum of 4 or more squares. We know it is always possible and we also have algorithms to do that.

My question is about going backward, that is if we only have a partial decomposition of $$m^2$$ as a sum of 4 (or 5) squares , can we rebuild $$m^2$$ If we have say 3 out of 4 or 4 out of 5 squares, can we reconstruct the square?

Comment: You actually don't need to write 'a difficult question' in the title.

Comment: I put difficult because I know it can be done if we knew the factorization of the number that is the sum of the given squares. But what I want to know is if it can be done without knowing the factorization of the sum of the given squares. Can the same algorithm (or some other algorithm) that works forward to decompose a given square into 4 or 5 squares be used to "reconstruct" the square when we are missing just one square out of 4 or 5?

Comment: I do not deny you. I just meant that your title should be more descriptive rather than telling us whether the question is difficult or easy.

Comment: Obviously not uniquely. There are numbers that can be represented in a lot of ways as a difference of two squares. The number of solutions of $N=A^2-B^2$ for some $N\not\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ is essentially $d(N)$, that is unbounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not uniquely.

Since for instance, given $a=3, b=5, c=11$

$18^2= 3^2+5^2+11^2+13^2$
$78^2= 3^2+5^2+11^2+77^2$

As we can write $(m+d)(m-d) = a^2+b^2+c^2$
there are as many solutions for $m,d$ as there factorisations of $a^2+b^2+c^2$.

Comment: what if we don't have  the factorization of  a^2 +b^2 + c^2?

Comment: Without factorisation, you can note that since the difference between two successive sqaures is $(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$, there is an upper bound on $d$, in fact $d \le \dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2-1}{2}$ so you can do a brute force search on $d$ for a solution.

Comment: can the algorithm that is used to decompose a square into a sum of 4 (or 5) squares be used to re-build a square when we  have partial information (3 or 4 out of 4 or 5). Or some other algorithm?

Comment: I wouldn't think there'd be any way to deduce a particular algorithm from the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have any three integers $a,b,c > 0$, and denote by sake of simplicity $k = a^2+b^2+c^2$. Then the equation
$$a^2+b^2+c^2 + y^2 = x^2$$
(where $x,y$ are the unknowns) may have more than one solution. Indeed this is equivalent to
$$(x-y)(x+y) = k$$
whose solutions are $$x= \frac{1}{2} \left( d+ \frac{k}{d} \right), \ \ y= \frac{1}{2} \left| d- \frac{k}{d} \right|$$
where $d$ is any divisor of $k$.

Comment: I realize my question was not clear enough. I know it can be done if we know the factors of k. But what I really want to know is if it can done when we don't have the factors of k. That is can the algorithm that decompose a square (or some other algorithm) into a sum of 4 or 5 squares be used to reconstruct the same square from 3 out of 4 or 4 out 5 squares. Our square is the unknown here.

Answer (score 0):

If we have 
$$
m^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2
$$
where we know $b$, $c$ and $d$ and that there is some unknown $a$, then you ask if $m$ can be uniquely determined.

Counter example:
$$
6^2 = 2^2 + 4^2 + 4^2 + 0^2 \\
9^2 = 7^2 + 4^2 + 4^2 + 0^2
$$

Comment: But $7,31,42,55$ are not squares.

Comment: Ok, fixed the counter example.

Comment: I know it can be done if we have the factorization of the given 3 or 4 squares. I meant, can it be done is we did not have the factorization.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking if, given $a,b,c$, we can find $x,y$ in,

$$a^2+b^2+c^2+y^2=x^2$$

The answer is ***yes***, but it may not be unique since,

$$a^2+b^2+c^2=(x-y)(x+y)$$

hence depends on the factorization of the LHS. For example, given $5,7,11$, then,
$$5^2+7^2+11^2 = 14^2-1^2$$
or
$$5^2+7^2+11^2 = 22^2-17^2$$

Comment: what if we don't know the factorization of the LHS? Is there a way to build x^2?